# Rails Postgres user CPU usage is 100%

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, devops

As shown in the image attached
[Postgres CPU utilisation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y693v.png)
what are the processes which are using a very high CPU?

Actual Postgres app processes are there which are working properly. 
If I kill these CPU intensive processes, still Postgres works fine.

Can someone have an idea of what these processes are? How to avoid/tune them?

Comment: And try setting up a firewall mate

Comment: @sevensidedmarble seems right